# How can share the user data while click menu label mouse right action open link in new tab

Tags: angular9

How can share the user data while click menu label mouse right action open link in new tab with out using local storage and session storage

I want to read the different user data in different tabs tab and when I duplicate or open new tab i can get the tab user data